# Session Management using Volley and Shared preferences in Android

Tags: android, session, sharedpreferences, android-volley

I am using [volley](/questions/tagged/volley) as a Network Library in my project. I need to maintain [session](/questions/tagged/session) using [cookie](/questions/tagged/cookie). I am getting cookie from server. So how should I get it using Volley and store in [sharedpreference](/questions/tagged/sharedpreference) for Session Management.

Comment: Your question is too broad I'm afraid, because it require several dozen lines of code (at least) to answer fully.  Can you narrow it down a bit?  Side note: If you don't want to deal with cookies, you can look into using cryptographic auth tokens.

Comment: You can guide me for how to get cookies from response

Comment: I have add this but it is giving me error like this   println needs a message and no record is fetched and set in Recycler View

Answer (score 0):

// Try this.

```
StringRequest req = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                         Log.i("response",response);
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                         Log.i("error",error.getMessage());
                        }
                    }){

                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    return getAuthHeader(context);
                }

                @Override
                protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                    // since we don't know which of the two underlying network vehicles
                    // will Volley use, we have to handle and store session cookies manually
                    Log.i("response",response.headers.toString());
                    Map<String, String> responseHeaders = response.headers;
                    String cookies = responseHeaders.get("Set-Cookie");
                    Log.i("cookies",cookies);
                    return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
                }

            };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

add this code in your Application class, it will save the cookies.

```
CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
        CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
```